# Generating UUID from Keccak-256 hash

Tags: randomness, keccak

Is generating Keccak-256 hashes with timestamp + nonce (ensured to be unique for each run), and taking its most significant 16 bytes sufficient to generate random V4 UUIDs?

Obviously the 13th hex character will be made 4, and 17th character will be made one of 8,9,a,b after the random generation. But I believe this is irrelevant to the question.

Comment: What is the size of timestamp + nonce? Is there a way that they will collide? You need at least 122-bit input for V4 UUIDs random part... and prefer the SHAKE series instead of Keccak-256.

Comment: UUIDv4 is for pseudorandom or true random sequences.  You want [UUIDv8](https://www.ietf.org/archive/id/draft-ietf-uuidrev-rfc4122bis-14.html) instead, which can be used to generate data predictably, as you're doing.

Comment: @kelalaka timestamp is 256 bits and nonce is 256 bits. nonce is auto-incremented and it is started from a silly value like 1234567890. even though timestamp is 256 bits since i am getting the now's timestamp, more than 200 most significant bits are always zero, don't know if that makes any difference.

Comment: @bk2204 hmm this is interesting. so in my case with auto-incremented nonce it would be something like auto-incrementing (nonce part) uuid prefixed with timestamp. wouldn't this be risky in collision considering I am only using timestamp + nonce? I would assume using more parameters associated to this id could be of help.

Comment: @AhmetYazıcı Deterministic processes have little entropy since one can define a little information to generate the next value. Hash functions, when assumed uniform random, can reduce the entropy a little bit with input increase to infinity, it tends to 0 decrease. With UUIDv4 you need 122 ( the previous was a typo as 112) random bits, so a uniformly randomly chosen nonce of size 256 bits will be enough for you. Last detail, how many UUIDS will you have? This is important since there may be a collision on the 112 bits due to the birthday-paradox.

Comment: @kelalaka If everything goes well, I expect to have about 10-100 billion UUIDs.

Comment: 100 billion UUID makes around $2^{37}$ this makes a [very very low collision](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=1+-+exp%28-0.5+*+10%5E10+*+%2810%5E10+-+1%29+%2F+2%5E122%29%29)

Comment: If the nonce is already unique then you would not need a timestamp. If the nonce is unique then you would not need a hash either, unless it may be too large for a UUID. So we come to the issue of how this is going to be used. If the hash is supposed to hide the serial number then this is not a good scheme. The timestamp will only make it harder if the adversary doesn't know the algorithm (which is generally frowned upon, Kerckhoff's principle). So: what requirements do you have for this UUID?

Comment: If you decided, one of us write an answer for you...

Comment: you were the most interactive and useful responder @kelalaka. If you answer I will upvote :).

Comment: I mean, if you might choose V4 or V8 ? did you decide that?

Comment: yeah, V4. because i have low amount of inputs, which I believe would cause low entropy for deterministic approach of V8.